# Using "If Value Is" tool in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I want to compare an input number to a constant number (<=), but I can't find the tool to do it in ModelBuilder. I have seen in an ArcGIS help website that a function named "if value is" exists but I don't know how to find it.

Do anyone know how to do it?

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-logical-tools-in-modelbuilder.htm

Comment: do you work with raster or vector ? Is your input number inside the dataset (pixel or attribute value) or a meta-variable (e.g. count of seclected entities, extent of the layer, existence of data like on your link...)

Comment: Hi, my input variable is the count of an occurence

Comment: please edit your question with more details about the occurence. The tool that you need could depend on the type of variable.

Comment: I have a set of points in a table that are grouped, in fact I have a feature named group in which the number of the group of each point is written (groups from 1 to 8). All my groups have a size of 6 except one, I want to find this group. If Value (of the size of my group) is (not) 6 then ... But I can't find this tool, it's not that I can't use it, it is that I can't find it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The **If Value Is** tool is part of the ModelBuilder toolbox of ArcGIS Pro.  To confirm that see [An overview of ModelBuilder tools](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-modelbuilder-toolbox.htm) for ArcGIS Pro.

If you cannot find it then I suspect that you are using ArcMap instead.  As you can see in [An overview of the ModelBuilder toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-modelbuilder-toolbox.htm) for ArcMap that tool, and none of the Logical tools are present in that earlier architecture.